# Get the version of a loaded SWF into a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader, swfloader

Is it possible to read the `SWF version` of a loaded SWF into a main one?

```
var mcl:Loader = new Loader();
mcl.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, prepareDisplay(mcl));
mcl.load (new URLRequest ('movie.swf'));

function prepareDisplay (mcl:Loader):Function {
    return function (e:Event):void {
        mcl.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, prepareDisplay);
        media_container.addChild(mcl);
        // how can I get the loaded swf version from here?
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by SWF version? How/where/when do you define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check the swfVersion property of the Loaders contentLoaderInfo LoaderInfo object.

```
trace(mcl.contentLoaderInfo.swfVersion);
```

Constants can be used from:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SWFVersion.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this utility class to get the version information from the player you are using or the flash version of the compiled swf.

https://github.com/jamestomasino/tomasino/blob/master/org/tomasino/utils/Version.as

Just use:

var compiledSwfVersion:int = Version.COMPILE_FLASH_VERSION;